# How to match and blacklist GMail address by regexp

Tags: regex, pcre

I would like to match and block address like `foo.bar@gmail.com`. But it isn't that easy, since any of following:

```
foobar@gmail.com
fo.o....b..a..r@gmail.com
foo.bar+goo@gmail.com
fo.ob.ar+something@gmail.com
```

Is alias for same email account. Is it possible to create regexp that matches all possible aliases? Or do I have to normalize (remove dots and text after `+`) all gmail addresses before applying filters/blacklist?

I could go with : `f[.]*o[.]*o[.]*b[.]*a[.]*r[.]*(+.*)` but it looks ridiculous for longer email and probably has bad performance

Comment: Do you want to match all gmail based ids which have foo followed by bar in the text?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I want to match just 'foobar@gmail.com' but ignoring all `.` characters and everything after `+`, including the `+` itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be a regex such as

```
f\.*o\.*o\.*b\.*a\.*r(?=.*\@gmail\.com)
```

This pattern basically says after any letter of `foobar` there may be some unknown number of dots `.`. You can always work from here on now and expand the expression to something like this

```
f[\.-_]*o[\.-_]*o[\.-_]*b[\.-_]*a[\.-_]*r(?=.*\@gmail\.com)
```

Here we also accept unknown numbers of hyphens and underscores.

**Example**

Here is an example in python:

```
# import regex

string = 'fo.o....b..a..r@gmail.com'
pattern = r'f\.*o\.*o\.*b\.*a\.*r(?=.*\@gmail\.com)'
test = regex.search(pattern, strings[0])
print(test.group(0))
# foobar
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess there really is no better way.

Comment: Alternatively, like you said, standardizing by removing special characters is maybe a more readable option.